# Python selenium click

Tags: python, selenium, click

How can I get page sources from this source code for all pages? I don't have any "next".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of Selenium you should use requests (and bs4) for this task:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://my_site.com" + rest_of_the_link)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: What if I am on page active and I want to go the next page and then also?

Comment: Do you want to enter the page or just get the source of it?

Comment: Yes, I dont  know how to get second page when I am on page active

Comment: After connectiong to a page using `driver.get(first_url)` use it again with the new url

Comment: Is it possible to set in this way? When I'm on page 1 the class is "paging active". Other pages have class "paging number". When I'm on page 2, the page 1 has class "paging number",  page 2 class "paging active" and other pages class "paging number". I want to go to the next pages.

Comment: I don't see any problem.

Comment: Can you help me do this? I'm new in Python

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
 webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/ball-page2']")).click();
```

the xpath will try find the url that is mentioned, if that exists it will click on that.

Comment: What if these links are different? I have /ball-page2 and /ball-page3?

Comment: whichever link you need to redirect to give that. That will work.

Comment: Note: you can't provide 2 links and click on that, because the first link will redirect and the second link will not get clicked.